# Spatial translational invariance for de Sitter spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, symmetry, diffeomorphism-invariance, de-sitter-spacetime

Consider de Sitter spacetime in the 'flat slicing' i.e. in the coordinates $$ds^2 = a(\tau)^2\left[-d\tau^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2\right],$$

where $x,y,z$ are Cartesian coordinates for space and $\tau$ is the conformal time. $a(\tau)$ is the scale factor. I am curious about translational invariance in such backgrounds. From the line element one can see that we lose (conformal) time translational symmetry since the metric manifestly depends on the (conformal) time $\tau$.

What about translations in space? Again, from the metric it seems like $\textbf{x} \to \textbf{x} + \textbf{c}$ for some constant $\textbf{c}$ should leave the metric unchanged. However, intuitively I think that since the background is curved, for larger separations I should see more curvature effects. Is saying that physical effects therefore depend on (spatial) separation alone just another way of interpreting (spatial) translational invariance? Since none of this depends on the form of $a(\tau)$ is this also true for any FLRW background?

Comment: It is maximally symmetric spacetime, so even the curvature will remain invariant under such translation. So no curvature effect